# Applescript - drag/drop file attachment to open new email

Tags: macos, email, applescript

Anyone know the Applescript snip that will open a new email with the file attachment that has been dragged/dropped on the Applescript script? (Google hasn't been a help.)

I've found commands that open a new email and prompt for the file attachment,

```
set theAttachment to (choose file without invisibles)
```

and snips that allow hardcoding the path to the attachment,

```
set theAttachment to (((path to desktop) as string) & "myFile.jpg) as alias
```

but none that allow dragging and dropping of the file attachment on the Applescript script icon.

**Edit 11/28/10:** Found and answer [MacScripter / AppleScript | OS X](http://macscripter.net/viewforum.php?id=2) and added it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was given this on [MacScripter / AppleScript | OS X](http://macscripter.net/viewforum.php?id=2) and it works fine:

```
property Myrecipient : "some email"
property mysubject : "some subject"
property EmailBody : "some body text"


on run
    tell application "Finder"
        set sel to (get selection)
    end tell
    new_mail(sel)
end run

on open droppedFiles
    new_mail(droppedFiles)
end open

on new_mail(theFiles)
    tell application "Mail"
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:mysubject, content:EmailBody}
        tell newMessage
            make new to recipient with properties {address:Myrecipient}
            tell content
                repeat with oneFile in theFiles
                    make new attachment with properties {file name:oneFile as alias} at after the last paragraph
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
        activate
    end tell
end new_mail
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an AppleScript [open handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript).  Here's a simple example that handles multiple files by opening a new outgoing email for each.  Lots of variations are possible:

```
on open what
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with f in what
            set theAttachment to f
            set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"My Subject", content:"My Body"}
            tell content of theMessage
                make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after last paragraph
            end tell
            tell theMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"Some One", address:"someone@somewhere"}
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end open
```

There is a lot more detail about `handlers` in Matt Neuberg's book *AppleScript: The Definitive Guide*.

Comment: That doesn't want to work for some reason; it opens a new email but doesn't attach the file.